# Unwrap word in a row of sliding menu (jfeinstein10)

Tags: android, word-wrap, slidingmenu

How can I unwrap word in a row of sliding menu (jfeinstein10) ? When I designed the sliding menu on my tablet, it worked fine. However, the text got wrapped when I opened the program on my phone (Smaller screen size).

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can make the menu wider so that it fits all the rows in 1 line each using 
`setBehindWidth` or `setBehindOffset`

or you could set the `singleLine` property on the TextViews in the list

in XML: `android:singleLine`

in code: `setSingleLine(true)`

Comment: I cannot vote up since I don't have enough reputation points. So sorry. I will vote up your answer when I have 15 reputation points